# How to pop (right) a token list with expl3?

Tags: expl3, token-lists

The `expl3` package provides `\tl_put_right` which enables us to append tokens to the right side of the current content of a token list variable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \foo
\tl_set:Nn \foo {bar}

\begin{description}
\item[Before:]
  \foo
\item[Put right:]
  \tl_put_right:Nn \foo {s}
  \foo
\end{description}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

But I'm missing a `\tl_pop_right` similar command (which does exist for sequences: `\seq_pop_right`).

**Edit:** What I have in mind for the  command `\tl_pop_right` is to pop the content of the token list given in its argument: if `\l_tmpa_tl` contains "baz", `\tl_pop_right:n {\l_tmpa_tl}` should leave "ba" in the input stream.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would make sense. The normal argument of `\tl`-commands are tokens in plural, not one token.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure to understand your comment. I'll edit my question in order to be more explicit.

Comment: I mean your commands are not symmetric. ` \tl_put_right:Nn \foo {ssssss}`  adds 6 `s` to `\foo`. What do you expect `\tl_pop_right` to do?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, they are not symmetric. I'm looking for the equivalent of the `pop` method of lists in `Python` (see my edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an even more powerful operation, namely `\tl_range:Nnn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \db_tl_pop_left:NN
 {
  \tl_set:Nx #2 { \tl_range:Nnn #1 { 1 } { 1 } }
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \tl_range:Nnn #1 { 2 } { \tl_count:N #1 } }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \db_tl_pop_right:NN
 {
  \tl_set:Nx #2 { \tl_range:Nnn #1 { -1 } { -1 } }
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \tl_range:Nnn #1 { 1 } { \tl_count:N #1 - 1 } }
 }

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {{ab}cdef}

\db_tl_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl

\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl

\db_tl_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl

\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl

\stop
```

The output on the console is

```
> \l_tmpa_tl={ab}cde.
<recently read> }

l.21 \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

? 
> \l_tmpb_tl=f.
<recently read> }

l.22 \tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl

? 
> \l_tmpa_tl=cde.
<recently read> }

l.26 \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

? 
> \l_tmpb_tl={ab}.
<recently read> }

l.27 \tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
```

Your simpler function could be implemented as

```
\cs_new:Nn \db_tl_lastitem:n
 {
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { -1 } { -1 }
 }
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \db_tl_lastitem:n
 {
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { -1 } { -1 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\lastitem}{m}
 {
  \db_tl_lastitem:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lastitem{abcdef}

\lastitem{abcd{ef}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to throw away the last item:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \db_tl_nolastitem:n
 {
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { \tl_count:n { #1 } - 1 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\nolastitem}{m}
 {
  \db_tl_nolastitem:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\nolastitem{abcdef}

\nolastitem{abcd{ef}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The fact that `\tl_range:nnn` and `\tl_range:Nnn` are in the “candidates” should not be of a concern: the functions are useful and they should stay. Perhaps the name could change.

With “non candidates”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \db_tl_nolastitem:n
 {
  \tl_reverse:f
   {
    \tl_tail:f
     {
      \tl_reverse:n { #1 }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_tail:n { f }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_reverse:n { f }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\nolastitem}{m}
 {
  \db_tl_nolastitem:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\nolastitem{abcdef}

\nolastitem{abcd{ef}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact I don't want to get the last item, but to remove it.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Easy enough. `;-)`

Comment: I knew it couldn't be difficult, especially for you, but warned you about my initial request in order to accept your answer :) BTW, is it safe to rely on `tl_range` which is currently in `l3candidates`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I added an implementation with `\tl_tail:n` and `\tl_reverse:n`